# Video playback from remote filesystem lag on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, filesystems

I have laptop running Ubuntu 14.10 and used for watching movies from my server. I've installed vlc player but faced with the bug: At approximately 40 minute (can ve different for various videofiles) of playback video begun lagging so hard so it impossible to watching it further. Than I tried other players (totem, mplayer) but it didn't help. So I begun to experiment and there is my conclusion:

1. It's not a server issue: I've tried to switch to nfs instead of samba but it didn't help;
2. It's not a hardware problem: Lags appeared over lan as well as over wifi;
3. It's not a wireless driver problem: Playback over dlna (which in fact is a simple http   stream) runs smoothly.

So 3rd statement pushed me into the considiration that bottleneck is in something that mounts nfs, smb, etc on local filesystem. Is it done by the kernel job or some kernel module?

I know that this question sounds weird but this so much interesting for me. Would appresiate any advice how I can make ubuntu to playback video smoothly.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a server issue? A similar issue occurred on a network file-server that had a screen-saver that started after a fixed period of time and used many CPU cycles [3GL screen-savers *do not* belong on servers]; of course, while someone was using the machine, or a LAN event occurred, everything was OK. It might be another process that begins a set time after the server appears idle.

Comment: I'm quite sure of that. I`ve been watching video for a long time from this server with my Windows PC and it run perfectly. This is very simple server running on ArchLinux and has no other redundant stuff that might slow it down.